# Reputation in Stack Overflow meta

Tags: discussion, support

About the new Stack Overflow meta:

1. Do [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Stack Overflow meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) have the same reputation shared between the sites?
2. If I earn some reputation in meta, will it reflect in the parent site total reputation and vice versa?
3. How are badges and privileges shared between these two sites?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You do not have independent reputation on Meta; instead it is periodically synchronized from the main site to Meta (once an hour). You cannot earn reputation on Meta.

Badges are not shared, you can still earn badges on Meta.

Quoting from the [What is "meta"? help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Comment: If I cannot earn reputation on meta, what will happen when someone upvote/downvote my questions/answers?

Comment: @arulmr: You don't earn reputation. All it does is reflect community sentiment on that post. You can still earn voting related badges; e.g. if your question gets 10 upvotes you earn the *Nice Question* badge.

Comment: @arulmr: as a consequence, downvotes do not cost you anything either.

Comment: Badges are not shared means if I get nice question badge on meta, it will not be appeared on stack overflow?

Comment: @ZobiaKanwal: yes. What did you expect it to mean?