# Is it important to be a good citizen on Stack Overflow Meta?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I just want to complain or give my opinion, and I don't want to check if it's a duplicate, or worry about the heavy burden of the scrutiny of my peers.

Can I do that here?

Comment: We still require some research and voting is a bit different http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Based on this eariler summary of reputation effects,  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250888/reputation-in-stackoverflow-meta?rq=1, it looks like I can't be a total idiot here because it will affect my overall SO rep.  SO is like No Exit.

Comment: the sync is only one way. Negative votes on meta don't affect rep on SO non-meta. (which is actually explained in the answer you linked to)

Comment: @geneorama Read the link from rene...

Comment: Rants and random venting will get you nowhere here. Better come prepared: you are free to discuss policy, attitudes, and decisions on questions and answers. The regulars on Meta are aware of the Meta-effect (and you may want to investigate that) but AFAIK we try to control ourselves. But you're still addressing real humans, not chat bots.

Comment: @geneorama well, there is a thing called the meta-effect that most often leads to votes on a post you advertize on meta

Comment: @Rizier123 Point taken.  Despite the "one way" nature of votes, I still have to worry building a useful resource here in meta.

Comment: @geneorama, you could go outside and scream.

Comment: @ Previous comments... so now that I've asked a dumb question (as quantified by downvotes), should I just delete this? That seems jerky, even jerkier than asking a bad question.

Comment: I guess that depends on how successful it was in providing you closure with what is currently bothering you. Only you can tell.

Comment: @RadLexus good point, I didn't mean to suggest that we shouldn't treat people like people.

Comment: haha, up to three downvotes.  Oh well, seemed like a legit question to me.  I mean you can't get more much  more meta than asking about asking things in a forum about asking things about asking things.

Comment: I believe the downvoters are questioning your statement, as it can be read as "can I vent my frustration in here?" I am all for venting and enjoy the occasional rant - but make sure it is *on topic for Meta*. If you have something on your chest and it's related to SO, by all means do post in here!

Comment: @geneorama Only because a question on meta gets downvoted doesn't need to mean it is bad or off-topic. As already linked in the first comment, voting on meta shows dis-/agreement.

Comment: Ah - you may want to read [What is Meta?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: You can leave borderline rude comments.  That's what I do.  Also, get stuffed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this is not a place to just vent. We still require posts to be about Stack Overflow, to be researched, to have a clear problem statement and to have to be about the policies, guidance and working of the site.

Voting on Meta is a bit different than on Main. Voting will not affect your reputation on main but it does indicate agreement/disagreement and the meta crowd here is full of opinions.

The best place to really vent is outside, probably facing the sea, and yell as loud as you can.

For moderate venting you can see if there is a chat room that is open for that and if not you can create the Vent room. I expect it to become popular.

Comment: *Probably facing the sea.* And preferably in a sunset. If you can't afford the sea, consider facing the trees. The sunset you can always afford.

Answer (score 2):

@rene gave the right answer which is basically "Read the Manual", which is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

The main point that answers my question is:

> This is not a random discussion area; rather, it's a place for improving our community and website, together.

Which means that you're still on the hook for making a better world, even on meta.

*sigh*

Comment: There's a whole load of Internet outside of the SE network where you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Yeah, but it'd be nice if there was a place in SO where you could ask questions without fear of judgement and ridicule (edited)

Comment: You could create that enlightened forum. Be the change you want to see in the world (elsewhere)!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, sorry but I changed "internet" to "SO" (which affects your response).  I do think SO is great, but  are times when I want a place to interact with SO without having to worry about every little thing I say being permanently judged.

Comment: Oh; in that case, tough.