# I got a job thanks to Stack Overflow. Is there a way to notify?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I mean, I applied through Stack Overflow to a job and after all the process, interviews, tests, I got the job. Isn't it useful (at least for statistics) to let them know I got the job thanks to their INSISTENT job ads? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: congrats by the way :)

Comment: Given the "INSISTENT" - it's difficult to tell whether you're not wanting the job ads to show anymore, or whether you want to offer thank you in someway for SO Job's to have connected you with employment - which is it? (note I'm a site moderator - I'm not a developer on the Jobs project)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I totally want to thank SO for introducing me to the company :)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy *(at least for statistics)* - this suggests something else as well: helping you indicate a conversion rate for Job ads.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy yeah I mean there are several sites for software developers to get jobs but SO has so many things and maybe that can completement the jobs part... Maybe just so other companies are encouraged to publish their positions there

Comment: This would definitely be helpful for machine learning, i.e. to improve matching.

Comment: How about converting this post to a feature request?

Comment: @CherubimAnand To be honest, I'm leaning more towards a way to let Jobs know employment was achieved through their site. A simple button or so, for the purpose [Glorfindel](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334065/i-got-a-job-thanks-to-stack-overflow-is-there-a-way-to-notify?noredirect=1#comment392464_334065) mentioned

Comment: YOU MUST WORK!  APPLY!

Comment: @CubeJockey A simple button or so sounds lovely, simple and let's hope, effective.

Comment: I'm actually fairly shocked that Jobs doesn't collect this information (I assumed it asked the employer for feedback on hiring through SO - as this would be more anonymous for SO users - or when hired through other means...though this could be inferred, though not 100%, from a removal of a posting and no response from poster). Otherwise how is one suppose to determine the effectiveness of Jobs, correlation between ad viewership and hire (see Glorfindel's comment), build other models (statistical or otherwise), and determine a number of other metrics?

Comment: @JGreenwell I was about to ask the same, in fact, one of my ideas used this I-through-but-no-they-don't-collect information.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to do this (aside from noting on Meta, as you've done). You're right that this would be really useful, though. We don't have concrete plans for this feature, although it's something we'd like to build in the future - if you have suggestions or ideas about this, please share.

Also, congrats on the new job :)

Comment: Thank you Donna, since you already have the information of the applicants, it could be really nice to know how many applicants are per tags, or per company, or country and also show some numbers for new companies to let them know that the job ads really work... Whenever you plan to build this feature I'd be more than happy to help :)

Comment: Funny to see a SE employee with only 1 rep!

Comment: Thanks @TachúSalamanca! I'll share your feedback with the team. We won't have a definite timeline for this right away, but I'll provide an update when we start early research/planning.

Comment: I am curious to know about 1 rep.

Comment: @Rasel sure, what would you like to know?

Comment: Why you have just single reputation though you answered a lots ques.

Comment: @Rasel I believe this was mentioned in some other meta question. If I'm not mistaken SE employees can opt to not receive any reputation, and in fact I know that they may even opt to not show the diamond in their name (there was some question about users performing mod actions without a diamond and this was the answer).

Comment: @Rasel the 1 rep is Donna's reputation for Stack Overflow. [You don't gain reputation for answering questions on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250888/reputation-in-stackoverflow-meta).

Comment: @Rasel yes, what Alasdair said.

Comment: @Donna hm, I guess you should have rep on UX Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm not sure such a statistic would be useful... You can't depend on users to be give proper feedback: I suppose many people who have gotten a new job don't care to inform SO about it. Would such a statistic be significant/useful? Or would it introduce a huge bias and become useless? I guess it'd be better if filled by the employer.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski if the employee is satisfied with Jobs.SO, I assure you they would be glad to provide feedback.

Comment: @Braiam that part: *"if the employee is satisfied"* introduces a bias, which is my point. Can you depend on a biased stat? I think *employers* would be more consistent in providing feedback (and you would get less *false* information from this channel).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski well, what we want to know is if they got the job, they are satisfied that Jobs.SO allowed them to find a job.

Comment: @Braiam yes, but what's that info worth without knowing the opposite side of the coin? How many are *not* satisfied? What's the ratio of satisfied people (you can't know that with just an absolute value). That kind of stuff. I'm not saying this stat is a bad idea, I'm just providing some matter for thought.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski "what we want to know is **if they got the job**" if they didn't we could just presume they didn't.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I actually stated in my comment to the main question that I assumed SO was collecting this data from employer (SO user's privacy) so I agree with that approach for *confirming someone got the job through SO jobs*. However, employers would also introduce different biases and may try to bump up their "hired" stats by saying they hired someone from here when it came from somewhere else - including when a person hears about the job here and applies on the companies website directly or other such. So argument to start on the SO user side can also be made -point is it should start

Answer (score 36):

You thank Stack Overflow by being an active member of the community, as pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215597/295232). Just be sure you don't spend so much time here you aren't able to do your regular job anymore, that would be counterproductive.