# Why question about availability of Azure features was left closed by review queue after my edit

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Very new to asking question on this site. I [had a question closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781342/plan-not-supported-for-selected-region-and-operating-system) due to lack of clarity and detail. Fair enough, and I agree with the initial assessment. I was also a bit rude about Azure chat support... my bad. However, I edited the question and when it was reviewed for re-open... [people just voted to keep it closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27596905). This is where I'm lost... because there is no information provided about *why* they voted to keep it closed. From my perspective, the problem I'm facing is quite clear... I'm trying to do something the MS docs state you can do but I'm unable to do it. Answers could be either "you are being an idiot, here is why/how you can/can't do what you are trying" or "this looks like a bug in Azure... sure glad you posted this here where Microsoft told you to post it because the Azure Function App dev team monitors questions with the azure-functions tag."

Honestly, I'm lost. I thought I was following directions, doing what I was told to do, but I'm hitting a wall.

Comment: The question doesn't look unclear, but I don't think it's on-topic, since it's not about a programming problem - it looks like a question for customer support.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1426539)

Comment: It’s possible close voters initially chose the “unclear” reason because they weren’t positive this wasn’t a programming issue and that’s what they wanted clarified. If you vote to Leave Closed you don’t get the option of changing the current close reason.

Comment: OK, I can accept that except Microsoft clearly asks people to post questions here on Stack Overflow because the dev teams monitor the ones tagged for them. It seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: Whatever Microsoft does is not our problem. They can say anything they want, take it up with them if they give users bad advice. Many questions about Azure are on-topic here. But yours is simply a customer support question.

Comment: Yeah, I get that... it's just hard to get in that frame of mind when you are busy beating your head against a wall. Anyway, thanks for the responses.

Comment: So.. should I answer my own question and just reference yivi's comment? Or does that screw up reputation points or something? Not sure what proper etiquette is for when the person who asks the question is made to realize it was a stupid question...

Comment: There is no reputation in "meta", so be at ease in that concern.

Comment: Regarding the question, do as you wish. Maybe it is not the most useful question to leave around. If you already got your answer, you can just delete it.

Comment: @yivi There is no reputation in `meta` means?

Comment: That actions in meta cannot directly affect your reputation, @KUMAR.

Comment: @yivi but my `SO` & `meta.stackoverflow` have same reputation??

Comment: @KUMAR Yes, exactly.

Comment: @KUMAR You can't gain or lose SO rep on meta.SO, even though your SO rep total appears on the menu bar.

Comment: @ yivi how is it , suppose if i  ask question & gave answers in `meta.stackoverflow` than reputaion is not increased in that??

Comment: @yivi  these both account are linked to each others??

Comment: @KUMAR No, as as I said earlier, actions in meta cannot directly affect your reputation. Your reputation is simply copied from the main site.

Comment: @KUMAR See [Reputation in Stack Overflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250888/11682469) (and duplicate target)

Comment: @yivi but if ask questions on meta & someone give me an answer & i accept that then what then i can get 2 point sreputation on accepting it similar as SO.

Comment: @KUMAR I think my previous comments have already made clear that no, you do not earn reputation in meta.

Comment: @yivi okay sir , but tell me one thing what is the benefit of `meta.stackoverflow` platform??

Comment: @KUMAR See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917/11682469)

Comment: @Jeanne Dark okay sir thanks......

Comment: If you see a place on Microsoft asking customers to post questions here *without the distinction that the question must be programming related*, can you post the link here? If they're sending general customer service inquiries here, we might need to talk to them to indicate that that's not what SO is for (preventing further frustrating situations like yours).

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I'll look to see if I can find where the specific wording was that pointed here. I believe part of the problem is that what I'm facing tracks from their automated solution workflows as a technical issue even though it's really a bug in their Portal. I'll take full responsibility however for my frame of mind at the time I posted which prevented me from recognizing that my issue was 100% unrelated to programming.

Answer (score -1):

So pretty much everyone who commented here indicated in no uncertain terms that [I was attempting to abuse Stack Overflow like it was an off-brand customer service call center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions). My bad. I now see the error of my ways and will delete the initial question that initiated all of this nonsense.

Comment: OK now, why was this answer not useful?  OH WAIT.... I didn't link to the post that described why Stack Overflow is not a customer call center?

Comment: If I had to guess, it may be because of the "Thanks everyone, -OP" fluff, which is considered superfluous in posts here.

Comment: Really? I mean... I'm all for brevity and clarity when it is called for, but that seems a bit harsh considering I was honestly just being appreciative of the comments and support.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to answer your question.  It could easily have been flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Sorry, still new around here.

Comment: I've updated title of the question (please review that and see if it aligns with your question) and closed as duplicate.

Comment: Sure, new title works for me.